# Cannot create bind mount destination path '/var/www' is already a bindfs mount

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, mount

I went to `vagrant up` this morning and got this error.

```
VirtualMachine: Cannot create bind mount from '/mnt/vagrant-vflsf_7p872mq5085x' to '/var/www': Destination path '/var/www' is already a bindfs mount
```

Made no updates to my vagrant configuration `(1.9.1)` or my operating system `(MacOS 10.12.2)`.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem today, which turned to be due to some old invalid entries in my /etc/exports file on my host machine from destroyed vagrant boxes.

Open your /etc/exports file and remove any invalid entries (and/or edit the paths for existing entries).

I needed to also do a `vagrant reload`.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if two filesystems have similar names. The fix is to order them from least unique to more unique in whatever file you store your bind mountpoints in.

For instance, say you mount `/abc/this_dir` and `/abc/this_dir_too`

This will NOT work

```
/abc/this_dir_too
/abc/this_dir
```

This WILL work

```
/abc/this_dir
/abc/this_dir_too
```

The problem is that vagrant issues a ***really stupid*** command to find if a mount has already occurred:

```
mount | grep '^bindfs' | grep #{directory.shellescape}"
```

It's pretty obvious what will happen if one FS is a subset of the other.